# Word frequencies from strings in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, text, nlp, word-frequency

Is it possible to identify distinct words and a count for each, from fields containing text strings in Postgres?

Answer (score 26):

Something like this?

```
SELECT some_pk, 
       regexp_split_to_table(some_column, '\s') as word
FROM some_table
```

Getting the distinct words is easy then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM ( 
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(some_column, '\s') as word
  FROM some_table
) t
```

or getting the count for each word:

```
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM ( 
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(some_column, '\s') as word
  FROM some_table
) t
GROUP BY word
```

Comment: depending on your data, it might also help to wrap the column in a `lower()`

Answer (score 15):

You could also use the PostgreSQL text-searching functionality for this, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''hello dere hello hello ridiculous'')');
```

will yield:

```
  word   | ndoc | nentry 
---------+------+--------
 ridicul |    1 |      1
 hello   |    1 |      3
 dere    |    1 |      1
(3 rows)
```

(PostgreSQL applies language-dependent stemming and stop-word removal, which could be what you want, or maybe not. Stop-word removal and stemming can be disabled by using the `simple` instead of the `english` dictionary, see below.)

The nested `SELECT` statement can be any select statement that yields a tsvector column, so you could substitute a function that applies the `to_tsvector` function to any number of text fields, and concatenates them into a single `tsvector`, over any subset of your documents, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''english'',title) || to_tsvector(''english'',body) from my_documents id < 500') ORDER BY nentry DESC;
```

Would yield a matrix of total word  counts taken from the `title` and `body` fields of the first 500 documents, sorted by descending number of occurrences. For each word, you'll also get the number of documents it occurs in (the `ndoc` column).

See the documentation for more details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

Comment: there should be a `WHERE` before the `id < 500`.

Answer (score 6):

Should be split by a space ' ' or other delimit symbol between words; not by an 's', unless intended to do so, e.g., treating 'myWordshere' as 'myWord' and 'here'.

```
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM ( 
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(some_column, ' ') as word
  FROM some_table
) t
GROUP BY word
```

Comment: \s is a valid regex character set for any whitespace character

Comment: I downvoted because the answer clearly misunderstands regexes.

Comment: beautiful, thank you!