# Find count of predefined words using active record or pure postgres query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to get some text analysis. As a result I want to get count of some key words in all records like this:

`answer id: 1, text: 'some good text'`

`answer id: 2, text: 'some really bad text, angry angry angry text'`

and result should be like this:

`good: 1, bad: 1, angry: 3`

I don't want to select all records and then map them count this key words on ruby etc because of big amount of data. Also I find some solution:

`Answer.pluck('regexp_matches(text, \'\mMyKeyword\M\', \'gi\')').flatten.count`

Works fine for 1 keyword. This causes problem that I used to do database request per keyword. I'm using rails 4 and potgres. Any help appreciated

Comment: How the resultant `key` are taken, Aren't they are non-common words of the two strings

Comment: looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226202/word-frequencies-from-strings-in-postgres can help you, go to the answer that starts with `You could also use the PostgreSQL text-searching functionality for this, for example:`

Comment: keys are predefined in array

Comment: I saw this answer. But the problem is I got all words count when I while I'm  only interested in 5-10 words