# Postgresql - number of words overlap in the text

Tags: postgresql

I need the to count how many times the word is found in the text, and do this for every word in the where condition.

In the table **books**, I have the field **description** with following text:

**Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue id ipsum, chicken meatloaf commodo nisi. Aute burgdoggen nisi andouille. Duis beef ribs rump sausage, dolor occaecat ullamco turkey doner quis picanha tenderloin ad sirloin. Id flank burgdoggen, meatloaf non beef mollit. Andouille ipsum strip steak pork belly corned beef pancetta cupim laboris minim ut leberkas.**

**Consequat nostrud tongue, lorem drumstick pig deserunt proident ea velit. Sirloin strip steak drumstick minim chicken porchetta. Anim mollit qui strip steak meatloaf excepteur flank pancetta boudin. Magna tongue beef ad eu. Voluptate alcatra tail, pork aliqua spare ribs aliquip beef ribs sausage ea. Ham hock alcatra biltong, pork qui ut tempor reprehenderit dolor shank labore pig ullamco cillum turkey..**

If my search terms are **ipsum**, **bacon** and **nisi**, I would get following result:

```
**ipsum is found 3 times**
**bacon is found 1 time**
**nisi is found 2 times**
```

Is it possible to do this kind of query.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226202/word-frequencies-from-strings-in-postgres

Comment: `select count(*) from regexp_matches('a b aa A...', '\m(a)\M', 'gi') as t;`